# Cannot Save User Login Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, gridview

I've run into a bit of a wall and I can't seem to get the results I'm looking for. The desired results are to have data get saved when all three form fields are populated. Instead, I get a lblerror that the input is not being saved. I'm assuming it's an error from the clsdatalayer document, and not the page load file, but I'll include both just in case I'm wrong.

**clsDataLayer Code:**

```
// This function saves the User data
public static bool SaveUser(string Database, string Username, string Password,
string SecurityLevel)
{
    bool recordSaved;
    // Transaction for SQL
    OleDbTransaction myTransaction = null;
    try
    {
        // Opens OleDBConnection
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + Database);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

        //Setting value to myTransaction
        myTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        command.Transaction = myTransaction;
        string strSQL;

        // Creates strSQL and sets the value.
        strSQL = "Insert into tblUserLogin " +
        "(UserName, Password, SecurityLevel) values ('" +
        Username + "', '" + Password + "','" + SecurityLevel + "')";

        //Receives Input
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = strSQL;

        // Executes the Query
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Commit Changes to myTransaction
        myTransaction.Commit();

        // Closes Connection and saves record
        conn.Close();
        recordSaved = true;
    } //end try
    catch (Exception ex)//This produces warning, but not error. 
    {
        //Rollback changes
        myTransaction.Rollback();
        recordSaved = false;
    }//end of catch
    return recordSaved;//returns values     
}//ends function
```

**Page load code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class frmManageUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAddUser.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnAddUser_Click);//event for button
    }
    protected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clsDataLayer.SaveUser(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.accdb"), txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, ddlSecurityLevel.SelectedValue))
        {
            lblDisplay.Text = "The user was successfully added";
            grdviewUsers.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            lblDisplay.Text = "The user was not added.";
        }
    }//end protected void
}//end class
```

**Actual Page Code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/CIS407A_iLab_ACITLogo.jpg" />

    </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Security Level"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSecurityLevel" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">U</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" runat="server" Text="Add User" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblDisplay" runat="server" Text="[lblDisplay]"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Users:"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="grdviewUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="UserID" DataSourceID="ManageUsers" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="UserID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserPassword" HeaderText="UserPassword" SortExpression="UserPassword" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SecurityLevel" HeaderText="SecurityLevel" SortExpression="SecurityLevel" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ManageUsers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblUserLogin]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What exception do you get in SaveUser method - catch

Comment: I can't be sure. This is a homework assignment and it's just what we were told to include in the previous one we used. when I tried to remove it I received an error for not having any assigned values for return recordSaved

Comment: In the comment next to the catch block, you state that `this produces a warning, not an error`. If your code enters the catch, then it has caught an error, so `ex` should contain something. Try adding a breakpoint on your rollback instruction, and see what the value of ex.Message. It should give you a bit more to go on.

Comment: I see...I think...It says here "myTransaction.IsolationLevel' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using MS.Access as your database and for this engine, the word PASSWORD is reserved. If you really have a field with this name then you need to enclose the field in square bracket in every query.

Said that, your code is very weak and could be exploited with an Sql Injection attack, you should use a parameterized query

So, I would rewrite your SaveUser in this way

```
public static bool SaveUser(string Database, string Username, string Password,
string SecurityLevel)
{
    bool recordSaved;
    // Transaction for SQL
    OleDbTransaction myTransaction = null;
    try
    {
        // Opens OleDBConnection
        using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(....))
        using(OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
             conn.Open();   
             using(myTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
             {
                  command.Transaction = myTransaction;
                  string strSQL = @"Insert into tblUserLogin 
                       (UserName, [Password], SecurityLevel) 
                        values (@uname, @pwd, @level)";
                  command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                  command.CommandText = strSQL;
                  command.Parameters.Add("@uname", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Username;
                  command.Parameters.Add("@pwd", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Password;
                  command.Parameters.Add("@level", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = SecurityLevel;

                  // Executes the Query
                  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  myTransaction.Commit();
             }
        }    
        recordSaved = true;
    } //end try
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // I suggest to log somewhere the exception message here....
        myTransaction.Rollback();
        recordSaved = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand it's weak, this is a homework assignment and I'm attempting to follow the instructions--I believe we're going to work on security settings soon here. But thank you for the warning on both items. Will try to change, though I can't understand how this worked for the professor.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that your professor wants to go step by step, but really, nowadays, security is something that we should start to learn immediately. Also I suppose that you receive a plain text password through the interface of SaveUser and save it in plain text in the database. Another big no-no from a security stand-point. Well it is important that you know of this problems.

Comment: On the other side, here the Transaction is not needed. You have just one action against the database and if this insert fails there is nothing already executed to rollback

Comment: I see, that does make sense. I think I'd also feel a bit more comfortable running with security first, but I suppose at the same time it makes sense to have the basic understanding and platform for the security readied.

Comment: The parameters are required not only for security reasons, but also to ensure the correctness of the code. For example, with the current string concatenation if the passed password or username contain a single quote your query will fail with a syntax error. Try it.

Comment: So...on a whim, I removed the rollback transaction because it was hanging up each time it hit that issue (after replacing the code with your suggestions). You recommended inserting an exception message here but I cannot designate the message to ex. Tried to look up some options, didn't seem to work.

Comment: A bare bone log could be _File.AppendAllText(filename, ex.Message)_, just map the name of the log file to your APP_DATA directory (or just write everything about the exception with ex.ToString() instead of ex.Message)

Comment: Was hoping the exception would fix this, doesn't appear to. The weird thing is that nothing hangs up, or fails to load, the lblDisplay just says "User not saved", as commanded. I can't figure out where they code is going wrong in regards to saving it to the database.

Comment: Are you able to use a debugger and step through the code of SaveUser? If yes put a breakpoint on the _recordSaved = false_ line and hover the mouse on the ex variable. You could read the info about the error.

Comment: msg1"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'Password'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.\r\n  Any idea? Does this mean that somewhere I have ain incorrect Field Name?

Comment: Think I got it...Thank you so much for your help.